# How can I translate "Pardonu !"?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

As many people here, I'm learning Esperanto on Duolingo and it translates *pardonu* as *excuse me* or *sorry*.

Is it possible to translate it as *forgive me* or *pardon me* ?

Comment: "Yes." Though "Forgive me" probably is translated in a bit longer form "Mi petas pardonon". However "Pardon me" ("I beg your pardon") is quite British isn't it. The answers are likely to talk about contexts.

Comment: In Duolingo, the sentence was "Pardonu, mi estas viro." I thought the best translation of "Pardonu" was "Forgive me" but it wasn't the idea of Duolingo ...

Comment: @JoopEggen Can you write an answer that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Yes."

Though *"Forgive me"* probably is translated in a bit longer form *"Mi petas pardonon"*.

However *"Pardon me"* (*"I beg your pardon"*) is quite British - isn't it.

The context is decisive on the most fitting translation.